# Динамическое добавление optgroup по символам

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[image: Screen]

Мне нужно сделать так, чтоб тэг optgroup динамически оборачивал тэги option, а значением его был первый символ текста в option. То есть должна получиться такая разметка. Как это сделать в JS?

```
<select id="select">
    <optgroup label="A">
        <option value="1">Andromed</option>
        <option value="2">AnkosiManila</option>
    <optgroup>
    <optgroup label="B">
        <option value="3">Backend</option>
        <option value="4">Bravisiimo</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="C">
        <option value="5">Cokolada</option>
        <option value="6">Cerny</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="M">
        <option value="7">Mapping</option>
        <option value="8">Marroni</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="N">
        <option value="9">NugetPack</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="J">
        <option value="10">Jaguar</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Благодарю

Answer (score 2):

```js
function group(select) {
  const oldGroups = select.querySelectorAll('optgroup');
  
  for (const group of oldGroups) {
    const options = group.querySelectorAll('option');
    select.appendChild(select);
    select.removeChild(group);
  }
  
  const options = select.querySelectorAll('option');
  
  const groups = {};
  for (const option of options) {
    const firstLetter = option.innerText[0];
    if (firstLetter) {
      if (!groups.hasOwnProperty(firstLetter)) {
        groups[firstLetter] = [];
      }
      groups[firstLetter].push(option);
    }
  }
  
  for (const letter of Object.keys(groups)) {
    const group = document.createElement('optgroup');
    group.label = letter;
    select.appendChild(group);

    for (const option of groups[letter]) {
      group.appendChild(option);
    }
  }
}

const $select = document.querySelector('#select');
group($select);
```

```html
<select id="select">
        <option value="1">Andromed</option>
        <option value="2">AnkosiManila</option>
        <option value="3">Backend</option>
        <option value="4">Bravisiimo</option>
        <option value="5">Cokolada</option>
        <option value="6">Cerny</option>
        <option value="7">Mapping</option>
        <option value="8">Marroni</option>
        <option value="9">NugetPack</option>
        <option value="10">Jaguar</option>
</select>
```